# Updating entity concurrency in Datastore GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing my first web application using Google App Engine and Datastore. The developing
process was pretty simple, but I have a huge dilemma. I want to create a "like" mechanism for
user's status (like Facebook's "likes").

So I've made a "Status" entity that has a "likeIndex" property (I just want to sum the total likes). Now I want to make sure that when more than one user gives like to the status at the same time I won't have a concurrency problem.

Has I learned from my short experience with Datastore the flow goes like this:

1. (on update function call) userA and userB will take the same version of statusA object with likeIndex = 0 - calls happened in the same time.
2. userA will make likeIndex++;
3. userA will update statusA with likeIndex=1.
4. userB will make likeIndex++;
5. userB will update statusA likeIndex=1.

Instead of having in the Datastore statusA object with likeIndes=2, I have the object with likeIndex=1.
How can I handle the update process to avoid the concurrency problem. It sounds simple and common problem so I'm surprised it is hard for me to find a solution online.
(I'm working with JPA)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to read and write likeIndex within a transaction.
2. You're going to run into performance problems if you have a large number of people liking (ie more than 1 like/second).  You'll need to use a sharded counter.

Luckily for you, there's a tutorial that explains it all step by step.  Amazing!

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Comment: I came across this solution, but I wanted to go with the more traditional transactions one. Do you know of a guide for transactions using the EntityManager object? Thank you very much!